# sql server join multiple rows issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, rows

My stock sheet has following data divided in 3 parts..

1. Opening
2. Receipt
3. Issue
4. Opening has Date,Item, Qty, RefNo columns.
5. Receipt has Date, Item, Qty, RefNo Columns.
6. Issue has Date, Item, Qty, RefNo Columns.

My problem is there may any number of opening,receipt or issue. like for 1 opening row, 2 receipt row and 7 issue rows exists.
In this scenario If I use joins it duplicates left/right tables columns.

Desired Output would Be:

```
        Opening             Receipt                Issue          RefNo
1-10-21 Item-A 5000        ------------     1-10-21 Item-A 500    AE-569P
                                            1-10-21 Item-A 750    BE-369Z
                       1-10-21 Item-A 500
2-10-21 Item-B 500     2-10-21 Item-B 500   3-10-21 Item-B 650
```

and so on..

How to solve this?
Thanks,

Comment: What is your DBMS? Have you tagged `server` and actually meant SQL Server? Or are you using another DBMS like MySQL, Oracle, etc.?

Comment: So you want to show the rows kind of grouped by item. And there is just one opening entry per item. And if there are more than two receipts or issues per item you want them shown in separate lines (first the issues, then the receipts), but if there is only one receipt and issue for an item, you want them shown in the same line. Yes?

Comment: What makes Opening and Receipt to be in relation?

Comment: DBMS is SQL Server,

Comment: Opening, Issue and receipt stores in common table by having DB_Code as a type of transaction. I've developed CTE to saperate the transaction types. It is not fixed that every period Opening, Issue or receipt has fixed no of rows.. sometimes there may not be opening and only issue and receipt... The issue is with formatting and may be with joins...